# How to set order to tab in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added two custom tabs to my store on Product page from admin end. I want to set order to my tabs i.e First tab called 'Custom Prices' and second tab called 'Custom Quantities' now I want to set First tab as 'Custom Quantities' and Second tab as 'Custom Prices'

Answer (score 0):

First install easy tabs if you don't have it setup on your magento instance :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-easytabs.html

Refer to this step if you already have it:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/57958/